# Adding Chronicle Queue to project using Maven conflicts with Lombok

Tags: eclipse, lombok, chronicle-queue

I was using Chronicle Queue in a project that does not have Lombok. Everything was okey. Then I tried to use same Maven dependency in a project that have Lombok dependency. But it crashed this time. I see the below error in my all Lombok Getter and Setter annotations.

```
The package java.lang is accessible from more than one module: <unnamed>, java.base
```

I can run the project. But Eclipse shows red warning in classes that use Lombok annotations. Here is my Chronicle Queue dependency.

```
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.openhft/chronicle-queue -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.openhft</groupId>
      <artifactId>chronicle-queue</artifactId>
      <version>5.17.22</version>
    </dependency>
```

[Image Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bz7h8.png)

Any idea about solution? Thanks.

Comment: Which Lombok version do you use?

Comment: @JanRieke I use this "<scope>provided</scope>" , Is it the problem?

Comment: No, Lombok must be included as `provided`. The version is important, as older versions had some issues in combination with modules. You should use the latest version 1.18.10.

Comment: I tried the latest version, same issue continues. I think this is about Eclipse. Because I run the project correctly. The only problem is red warnings. That means there is no problem for compiler. I don't know how to solve.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, I think, that a transitive dependency of `chronicle-queue` has some classes in the `java.lang` package, which is not allowed anymore.

Basically, you have to exclude the `net.openhft:affinity` package.  Something like:

### Maven Snippet

```xml
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.openhft</groupId>
      <artifactId>chronicle-queue</artifactId>
      <version>5.17.22</version>
      <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>net.openhft</groupId>
                <artifactId>affinity</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>

    </dependency>
```

P.S. Techically, we were having the same problem with `chronicle-map` instead of `chronicle-queue`, but I believe it's for that same reason so I'm posting anyway.